# Remove unique values from a list and keep only duplicates

Tags: python

I'm looking to run over a list of ids and return a list of any ids that occurred more than once. This was what I set up that is working:

```
singles = list(ids)
duplicates = []
while len(singles) > 0:
    elem = singles.pop()
    if elem in singles:
        duplicates.append(elem)
```

But the ids list is likely to get quite long, and I realistically don't want a while loop predicated on an expensive len call if I can avoid it. (I could go the inelegant route and call len once, then just decrement it every iteration but I'd rather avoid that if I could).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The smart way to do this is to use a data structure that makes it easy and efficient, like [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> ids = [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(200)]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(ids)
>>> dupids = [id for id in ids if counts[id] > 1]
```

Building the `Counter` takes O(N) time, as opposed to O(N log N) time for sorting, or O(N^2) for counting each element from scratch every time.

---

As a side note:

> But the ids list is likely to get quite long, and I realistically don't want a while loop predicated on an expensive len call if I can avoid it.

`len` is not expensive. It's constant time, and (at least on builtin types list `list`) it's about as fast as a function can possibly get in Python short of doing nothing at all.

The part of your code that's expensive is calling `elem in singles` inside the loop—that means for every element, you have to compare it against potentially every other element, meaning quadratic time.

Comment: I think it would be more efficient with `itertools.ifilter`. (i was writing an answer with both `Counter` and `ifilter` but you do it faster ;))

Comment: @Kasra: Why? Using `filter`/`ifilter` instead of a generator expression/list comprehension means you have to wrap the test inside a function, which adds extra cost. (If you were just referring to not building the list if we don't need it, the easier way to do that is to just change the listcomp to a genexpr—but since he specifically says he needs to return a list, I don't think you can avoid building the list.)

Comment: @Kasra: The first list is just creating the test data. You need to get input data from somewhere.

Comment: @Kasra: Anyway, instead of guessing, from a quick timeit test on 10000 elements with 100 unique values, `[listcomp]` takes 1.88ms, `list(genexpr)` takes 2.25ms, `filter` takes 2.71ms, and `list(ifilter)` takes 2.91ms. So, using `ifilter` makes it 55% slower. At any rate, these kinds of micro-optimizations are rarely worth worrying about; once you get from quadratic behavior to linear, usually you can stop optimizing…

Comment: Ooops yeah, i miss that the first list is the input! i mixed it with what i had in my mind! i think i just made it more complex for myself!

Comment: Why not  `[i for i,j counts.items() if j > 1]`?

Comment: @Kasra: Sure, that works too. It's really just a matter of which you find more readable—or expect a novice to find more readable, depending on the question. I think it's a tossup here. (But notice that it's not clear whether the OP is using Python 2 or 3, which means that writing it your way would probably need a note on `items` vs. `iteritems`/`viewitems`, which may be enough to resolve the tossup…)

Comment: Yes,in python 3 `items()` is sufficient and in 2 we can use `iteritems` but in both cases i think this is more efficient instead loop over whole of the first list and check the condition for all of duplicates!

Comment: @Kasra: Oh, I see, you're suggesting we iterate the counter rather than the list, so it's O(k) instead of O(n) (where k is the number of duplicated elements). Yeah, that is faster--but it also throws away ordering, and the multiple copies of each dup (although you can fix the latter easily, the former you can't), and we have no reason to believe that's acceptable given the OP's code or description, so...

Comment: @Kasra: Also, since you still have to build the Counter, which requires iterating the whole list, you're just changing O(2n) to O(n+k), which is an improvement, but not a huge one. It's still linear. Repeating the same test as before, I get 1.79ms vs 1.89ms. So it's a measurable improvement, definitely, but not worth changing behavior for unless you really wanted the new behavior, I think.

Comment: As OP is looking for a fast and efficient way i suggested this solution, although  i'm agree with linear difference but for very long lists based on our RAM space the second could be better ;) .Anyway the difference is little and your answer is good! as always!

Answer (score 5):

You could do like this,

```
>>> ids = [1,2,3,2,3,5]
>>> set(i for i in ids if ids.count(i) > 1)
{2, 3}
```

Comment: Just a small addition if you want to end with a list:

    duplicates = list( set(i for i in ids if ids.count(i) > 1) )

Comment: `list(set(i for i in ids if ids.count(i) > 1))`

Comment: This is even slower than his existing code (although only by a constant factor of 2-ish). It does remove the `len` call, but that part didn't matter; replacing the `elem in singles` with `ids.count` means you're now searching every element every time, instead of searching just for the first match in just the duplicates.

Comment: Also, this destroys the order, and collapses all duplicates into 1, neither of which his original code did, so I don't think you can assume that's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this will work faster:

```
occasions = {}
for id in ids:
    try:
        occasions[id] += 1
    except KeyError:
        occasions[id] = 0
result = [id for id in ids if occasions[id] > 1]
```

Comment: Yeah, this is basically just a simple version of `Counter` implemented manually, so it'll be just as fast. (Or at least very close to it; `Counter` may be marginally faster by using `__missing__` instead of `except KeyError:`, but that's only going to make a small constant difference.) I think `occasions = Counter(ids)` is easier to read and harder to get wrong, but this is fine too—especially since it may be clearer to a novice who hasn't gotten used to thinking in terms of dicts why it helps.

Comment: Okay, I totally agree with you. Thanks for your answer, I was unaware of such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> l=[1,1,2,2,2,3]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> print([key for key,group in groupby(l) if len(list(group)) > 1])
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Just check if the group (in loop) is bigger than one, if it is keep it, otherwise don't.

Or use `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s=pd.Series(l)
>>> s[s.duplicated()].unique().tolist()
[1, 2]
>>>
```

It's very fast, because `pandas` is super fast.

Documentation:

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html
>
> Put cursor on the yellow part to view links.
>
> > https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas.Series.duplicated, and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about the order in which these ids are retrieved, an efficient approach would consist in a sorting step (which is O(N log(N))) followed by keeping ids that are followed by themselves (which is O(N)). So this approach is overall O(N log(N)).

Comment: But the sort itself is O(N log N), so the O(N) step doesn't matter. Plus, that destroys the order, and we don't know if that's acceptable, so you can't just assume it is.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work if the result must be in the same order.