# How to create a random sample of [n] elements for each unique element in list containing a certain string(with nested-loops?)

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am trying to create a list which contains a random sample (more specifically, a stratified sample).

My data consists of a list with several million telephone numbers (a string for each) which I splitted into a list containing 2 strings (for each number). 
The first string is the city code, by which the sample has to be stratified. I used

```
unique = list(set(citycode))
```

to get all unique elements from the main list (mainlist[0]).

Suppose I have ~1000 elements in list 'unique' and for each unique element I am trying to find 5 elements in 'mainlist' **randomly** which contain the number of unique[i] in mainlist[i][0]. 
For each match, both fields/strings of mainlist shall be appended to a new list, 'randomlist'. So the final list should contain 5000 telephone numbers.

I thought of using  nested loops for this, but as I am a beginner in Python and trying to use online tutorials to teach myself, I haven't really found a function or way to solve this. 
I am not sure in this case what would be a possible way of solving it.

Any ideas or input would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming two lists like:

```
main = [(123, xxxxxxx),...]
unique = [123, ...]
```

Then you can do something like:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(main)
out = []
for u in unique:
  i = 0
  it = (x for x in main if x[0] == u)
  while i < 5:
    try:
      out.append(main.pop(main.index(next(it))))
    except:
      pass
    i+=1
```

`out` will contain a list of tuples like those found in main, up to 5 per unique area code (will be less than 5, if main contains less than 5), randomly distributed.

**UPDATE**

Since you want to exclude area codes with too little representation all together, here's how you do that:

```
from random import shuffle
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(x[0] for x in main)
main = [x for x in main if c[x] >= 5]
shuffle(main)
out = []
for u in unique:
  i = 0
  it = (x for x in main if x[0] == u)
  while i < 5:
    out.append(main.pop(main.index(next(it))))
    i+=1
```

Comment: Thank you Logan!
The way you understood main and unique as lists is exactly as I meant it.

If I try to use your suggestion, I get the following warning (I assume not an error, but no Iteration takes place and out consists no elements after executing:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-900-8654d8ee647c>", line 6, in <module>
    out.append(numbers.pop(numbers.index(next(x for x in numbers if x[0] == u))))

StopIteration

Do I have to make certain changes to the code?

Comment: See my console output at https://imgur.com/BuwZKDJ.  I'm not getting any such error.  Check your syntax.  This error is raised when next() is called on an itterator with no additional values.

Comment: @Sven I made an edit that may help.  Try it this way and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I checked the mainlist, in which unfortunately aren't several elements for each number in unique - seems to be the reason why next() can't find additional values.

How can I create a sublist of 'mainlist' which only contains all the elements which appear n times? Then I would create a new list 'unique' of mainlist_n.

I tested your code without the while statement and out = [] returns a list of ~1000 elements - so that works splendidly.

Concerning the edit: I think it = [x for x in] has to be iter([x for x..] otherwise it is not iterable. Thanks!

Comment: @Sven It actually has to be (x for x in main), python uses an iterator with list comprehension, but you need to put it in parentheses to make it iterable.  If you don't care if an area code has enough members see above edit.

Comment: @Sven If you do care, and want to exclude the area codes with too few members like I you say, take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845051/remove-unique-values-from-a-list-and-keep-only-duplicates which uses Counter and list comprehension to modify main to return only values with 5 or more duplicates.  Then use unique = [x[0] for x in main] to build a new unique off of new main.

Comment: That solution works perfectly as you said in case that the areas with not enough numbers can be ignored or get < n numbers.

The thread you recommended used: from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(ids)
dupids = [id for id in ids if counts[id] > 1]
The form of the list used was id = [1234, 5678, ...]

In the case of main, the structure is main = [(123, xxx), (456, xxx) ...]
I am not quite sure which parameters in dupids should be changed to access x[0] in main via list comprehension here. While trying different things I always got: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: So I assume I have to set counts = Couter(main) # general list here
and then the id for id in ids (original thread) have to be set to other values. Or is it the counts[id] part (or counts[main] in my case, that has to be changed? I am slightly confused; your use of x for x in x was pretty straightforward, but then again, I have just started learning to code in Python
Thanks again, Logan!

Comment: @Sven It's no problem.  It's a bit different for you and involves more list comprehension. Something like, `c = Counter(x[0] for x in main)` then `over_five = [x for x in main if c[x] > 5]`

Comment: @Sven If you're new to Python, I recommend learning list comprehension ASAP.  It's crazy powerful and way more efficient than dealing with lists using loops.  http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python.  I may be biased though, as I use it extensively in Haskel as well.

Comment: @Sven I actually edited the answer to address that case as well, check out the update section.  Let me know if that solves your problem.